# How to display something else if an SQL column is empty with php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am having some trouble with getting this to work. I have an image gallery that is calling for the image link from the SQL database. Which works beautifully, however, if a user is only using 'pic1' and 'pic2' but 'pic3' and 'pic4' are empty in the database, I want to display a placeholder image instead. Any recommendations to do that?

```
    <li><a class="ns-img" href="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['pic1']; ?>"></a></li>
    <li><a class="ns-img" href="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['pic2']; ?>"></a></li>
    <li><a class="ns-img" href="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['pic3']; ?>"></a></li>
    <li><a class="ns-img" href="<?php echo $row_Recordset1['pic4']; ?>"></a></li>
```

Comment: @user3783243 Thank you for your reply! Dreamweaver is kicking the line back to me as broken, any suggestions?

<li><a class="ns-img" href="<?php if(empty($row_Recordset1['pic4'])) { echo 'donate.png' }{ else echo $row_Recordset1['pic4'];?>"></a></li>

Comment: @Cyndi There were a few typos there. I've corrected and moved to an answer.

Comment: On second thought is `$row_Recordset1['pic1']` simply a path to an image?

Comment: This question desperately needs more details about the actual problem. This is not simply a matter of displaying placeholder image. The questioner phrases the question completely differently in the comments to each answer.

Comment: @Steven correct!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do the check in SQL:

```
case when pic4 = '' then 'someimage.jpg' else pic4 end as pic4
```

or

```
case when pic4 is null then 'someimage.jpg' else pic4 end as pic4
```

if the data is `null` when not set.

This can be done in PHP as well:

```
if(empty($row_Recordset1['pic4'])) { 
    echo 'someimage.jpg';
} else {
    echo $row_Recordset1['pic4'];
    
}
```

or even

```
echo (empty($row_Recordset1['pic4']) ?  'someimage.jpg' : $row_Recordset1['pic4']);
```

for shorthand version.

Since your string has spaces you need to use `trim` as well:

```
echo (empty(trim($row_Recordset1['pic4'])) ?  'someimage.jpg' : $row_Recordset1['pic4']);
```

can be done in SQL as well:

```
case when trim(pic4) = '' then 'someimage.jpg' else pic4 end as pic4
```

Comment: Hey there! The short hand is definitely best, but it's still not displaying the 'someimage.jpg' replacement if  pic4 is empty. It will display pic4 if there is something in that column though. I'm stumped.

Comment: `var_dump($row_Recordset1['pic4'])` gives what?

Comment: Thank you for all your help so far! Same result, unfortunately :(

Comment: That must give back a variable type, length, and value.

Comment: It's not doing anything different when I var_dump, I assume it's because of how the image gallery is set up. Did you have any other suggestions on the replacement?

Comment: What is the `var_dump` result. I need to know that to know why it isnt working.

Comment: running `<?php var_dump($row_Recordset1['pic4']); ?>` produces NULL results on it's own. This database is setup to house a character profile. So my profile.php page is empty of specific data, the data is filled in by the specific ID for that person's login. So profile.php?id=12 and it fills in those details set for that user from the SQL database. Not every user has something in the 'pic4' column. It depends if that user when to their profile and submitted an image link. I am calling `$row_Recordset1['pic4']` to the gallery list to display the image, if there is one.

Comment: `NULL` evalutes to `true` for `empty()` so you should have `someimage.jpg` returned in that scenario. Is it just the attribute just empty or what is there? Demo of how it should be working https://3v4l.org/0CEZZ

Comment: So do you want no output if there isn't an image, or a placeholder? This should give placeholder.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231250/discussion-between-cyndi-and-user3783243).

Answer (score 2):

The PHP ternary or conditional operator could help you

```
<li>
    <a href="<?= $img ?: './images/default.jpg' ?>"></a>
</li>
```

This operator says, that if `$img` is empty or null the default image will be used.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work. There is no original place holder image. I would need to either put a link to an image into the SQL database, which is fine, and name it something like $row_Recordset1['temp'], as an example, but I am not sure how to tell it to display $row_Recordset1['temp'] if $row_Recordset1['pic4'] is empty

Comment: Quote from the original post: >  if a user is only using 'pic1' and 'pic2' but 'pic3' and 'pic4' are empty in the database, I want to display a placeholder image instead.

Comment: The LINK to the images, are contained in columns that are named 'pic#'. If the 'pic#' column is empty, meaning there is NO LINK in the table, then I want to replace that with a specific place holder. Your recommendation ignores the use of SQL entirely, which is the critical component to the question.

Comment: You should ask more detailed questions.

Comment: You don't seem to understand the question.

Answer (score 0):

This can be done in PHP as well:

```
<?php
   if($row_Recordset1['pic4'] == NULL){
       <li><a href="<?= $img ?: './images/default.jpg' ?>"></a></li>
   } else {
      <li><a href="<?= $img ?: './images/anyimages.jpg' ?>"></a></li>
   }
?>
```

You can also use while or forloop into same code.